# Is it still possible to have standalone Python elements in GStreamer 1.0?

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I have an application written with gst-python for GStreamer 0.10 that I am trying to port to GStreamer 1.0.

In my application, I have some custom elements written in Python (subclasses of `gst.BaseSrc` and `gst.BaseTransform`). Each python-element has its own file and is placed in `/usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/python` so that `gst-launch` and `gst-inspect` can pick them up (which they do).

This is very handy, since it makes it possible for me to experiment with different pipelines directly on the command line.

Now that I am trying to port my application (according to this guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0) it looks like even if it is still possible to write python-elements with PyGI, it seems like the possibility to store them in separate files and have them integrated in GStreamer is gone.

All examples I have found talks about placing the elements in the program you are writing and then registering them with a call `Gst.Element.register`, but if I would do so, it would only be possible to reach my custom elements directly from this program and I want them to work standalone (with gst-launch) without having to write my filter chains in a program.

So does anyone know if this is still possible with GStreamer 1.0?

Comment: And as usual when it comes to GSTreamer, only a few people has the knowledge needed to answer and those people really don't care about "simple" newbie questions. For this question and others I have tried IRC and even directly emailing people, but not a single response so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to help other people struggling with this, I am now answering this myself.

After some deep research I have now found out that it has not been possible to have any standalone python elements before gst-python 1.4.0 was released on 2014-10-20.

For the release notes take a look here:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/gst-python/1.4.0.html

Comment: Thank you very much for reporting your findings on this. It is frustrating sometimes getting help on these types of issues, so I applaud you for finding the answer and sharing with others. This really helped me.

Comment: Thank you. I am glad if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have the same issue that I had, but in the example from 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Novacut/GStreamer1.0  there is a mistake that was causing an error when I tried to register a new plugin. It is using

```
__gstdetails__ = (
    'Dmedia File Source',
    'Source/File',
    'Resolves a dmedia ID to a file path, then acts like a filesrc',
    'Jason Gerard DeRose <jderose@novacut.com>',
)
```

when it has to be:

```
 __gstmetadata__  = (
    'Dmedia File Source',
    'Source/File',
    'Resolves a dmedia ID to a file path, then acts like a filesrc',
    'Jason Gerard DeRose <jderose@novacut.com>',
)
```

Comment: As you can see in my new answer it has not been possible to do this before the 1.4.0 release of gst-python. You must have written your code in such a way that your Python elements was embedded in your Python program. Having standalone Python elements that are usable from other languages is a relatively new feature for GStreamer 1.0, but has worked in previous versions for ages.